# Running existing C++ code using Visual Studio starting from a Makefile

Tags: c++, windows, makefile

I am given a C++ project and I am trying to get it to run. I am given a folder with a few .cpp files, .h files, .o files, and files with no further extension. Additionaly, I am given a Makefile. To me it seems that this file was not 'intended' for Windows (as nmake does not work). I want to import the project to Visual Studio . I have installed make on my computer and ran `make -v Makefile` from the command line. This yielded the following response:

```
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-pc-mingw32
```

Nothing happens after this, no additional files are created. Frankly, I am not sure what this command usually yields (I think a .exe should be created?) as I am new to working with Makefiles (I would just use Visuals Studio Solution files). I feel like I am missing a few fundamental things here. Can somebody help me to clear things up and point me in the right direction?

This is the Makefile I am working with:

```
LDFLAGS=-lstdc++fs
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-g -O3 -std=c++17 -Wall -pedantic -I./ -I/usr/include/folder1 -I/usr/include/folder2
BIN=project1

SRC=$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ=$(SRC:%.cpp=%.o)

all: $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) -o $(BIN) file1.cpp main.cpp $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CXX) $@ -c $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(BIN)

distclean: clean
```

Comment: Not without a [mre]. You could try adding the source files to a new visual studio solution. Note that `-v` just prints the version then exits: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html#Options-Summary

Comment: I added the Makefile to the question. Let me know if there is another information that I could provide.

Comment: `make -v` asks make to tell you what version it is. I would recommend just running `make` (or `make -f Makefile`, but that is the default input filename) then reframing the question around the results that gives you.

Comment: There's nothing special in the make file, creating a visual studio solution from the source files should be trivial. The make file will need to be modified to remove Linux paths and libraries and gcc compiler flags

Comment: Thanks for your input so far. I tried to simply run the `make` command without the `-v` and this resulted in an error that files could not be found (owned to the Linux paths I presume). So I replaced the Linux paths with Windows paths, still receiving the same error (probably it's not this trivial to change the path). I figure that the best path of action is to not use the Makefile but simply create a new .Sln file that incorporates the same dependencies. Would you agree?

Comment: Changing the paths is not writing them in Windows format, but give the paths where **your** MSVC installation stores the relevant include files and libraries. IMHO it will be simpler to create a brand new solution.

Comment: You don't just need to change the paths, none of `LDFLAGS`, `CXX`and `CXXFLAGS` are valid for visual studio